# in Listview while scrolling and fast click on item unable to stop scroll, intead it will open a item?

Tags: nativescript

In listview inside i have listview template and its inside have different element and different tap event listener.

In IOS scroll fast and fast touch on screen.
it navigates to item page instead of stop scrolling so i would like to approach below method to stop scroll. Unable to fix.

Expected Result: To Stop Scroll
If touch on screen to stop scroll and then i touch on screen open item page.

Actual Result: It goes to els part, Unable to stop scroll.
While scrolling touch on screen(Tap event raised) instead of stop the scroll.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
  <ListView items="{{ menu }}" row="1"  id="mylist" >
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
      <GridLayout columns="auto, *">
        <Image src="{{ imageURL }}" row="0" cssClass="icon" tap="myTapListener"/>
        <StackLayout col="1" tap="myTapListener1">
          <Label text="{{ title }}"  cssClass="name"/>
          <Label text="{{ subtitle }}" cssClass="location"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate> 
  </ListView>
</Page



 exports.myTapListener = function(args) {
    var item = args.object;
    if(item.page.getViewById("mylist").isScrolling) {
        console.log("Scroll stopped: " + item.page.getViewById("mylist).isScrolling);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("unable to stop:" + item.page.getViewById("mylist).isScrolling);
    }
}

exports.myTapListener1 = function(args) {
    var item = args.object;
    if(item.page.getViewById("mylist").isScrolling) {
        console.log("Scroll stopped: " + item.page.getViewById("mylist).isScrolling);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("unable to stop:" + item.page.getViewById("mylist).isScrolling);
    }
}
```

Comment: When i touch on screen(tap Event raised) while scrolling.

Expected Result: To stop scroll  


Actual result is : Unable to stop scroll. It always return false.  


If i got true then i can stop by this approach   


`if(item.page.getViewById("mylist").isScrolling) {
        console.log("Scroll stopped: " + item.page.getViewById("mylist).isScrolling);
        return;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

The Js code needs to be:

```
var frame = require('ui/frame');

exports.myTapListener = function(args) {
    var page = frame.topmost().currentPage;
    if(page.getViewById("mylist").isScrolling) {
        console.log(page.getViewById("mylist").isScrolling);
    } else {
        topmost().navigate("module/a1")
    }
}

exports.myTapListener1 = function(args) {
    var page = frame.topmost().currentPage;
    if(page.getViewById("mylist").isScrolling) {
        console.log(page.getViewById("mylist).isScrolling);
    } else {
        topmost().navigate("module/a2")
    }
}
```

**args.object** in these event handlers is NOT the page object; but the item generating the event.  So you just need to reference to the currentPage which **frame.topmost().currentPage**

Comment: I trying to stop scroll then i tap to navigate but

`page.getViewById("mylist").isScrolling` while scrolling i got response false.